# Link migrated questions and answers to user account

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts, migration

I was a moderately active user on Gadgets.stackexchange. Most of my activity there dealt with Android, and those questions and answers were migrated here after Gadgets was closed.

I signed up for this site as soon as it went to public beta. I used the same OpenID credentials as on the Gadgets site, but my migrated questions and answers have not been linked to this account [like they're supposed to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64847/migrated-questions-to-android-will-they-be-linked-to-my-account/64849#64849).

Can someone give the system a nudge to complete the job? I can't believe I'm the only one with this issue.

Comment: I believe  my questions merged without any problems, but I've been on here since day 1 of private beta

Comment: I also have this issue.

Comment: Hmmm, I have the same issue (eg this question isn't linked to me: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/948/how-can-i-watch-ted-videos-offline-on-android ), though I might have confused things by starting my gadgets account from my `myopenid.com` ID, but creating this one on my google ID (and then linking my `myopenid.com` ID).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flag any questions that were not correctly associated to your new account and we will address them.

Comment: I have been, but they haven't all yet been fixed.

Comment: We have corrected the ones that have been flagged - if you find more please flag them and we will address them case by case.

Comment: Thanks. Will do.

Comment: @ale is this all taken care of now?

Comment: I'd found one more answer a couple days ago and flagged it, so, yes, it all looks complete. Thanks.

Comment: Is this still the procedure to handle unassociated posts and comments?

Comment: @Kyle if you see and issue, yes - flag it.

Comment: OK, I went through the posthistory.xml file and found my answers from gadgets.se and flagged the posts. There were a few comments as well - basically, anywhere the user is "Kyle Cronin" it's probably me