# Please merge Kyle Cronin with Kyle Cronin

Tags: support, status-completed, migration, user-accounts

We have several posts on the site, listed below, which belong to [Kyle Cronin](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/254/kyle-cronin) but aren't associated with his account (the username is greyed out), presumably due to migration from the Electronic Gadgets site.  Could a dev type person correct this?  Or provide mods the tools to do so?  :P

- [How to break in a new cell phone battery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/how-to-break-in-a-new-cell-phone-battery/1036#1036)
- [How can I store Android apps on my SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-can-i-store-android-apps-on-my-sd-card/629#629)
- [How to post a link to an android market app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/609/how-to-post-a-link-to-an-android-market-app/610#610)
- [Is there anyway to watch wmv and or divx videos on android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/585/is-there-anyway-to-watch-wmv-and-or-divx-videos-on-android/586#586)
- [iPhone ringtones and other sounds on Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/547/iphone-ringtones-and-other-sounds-on-android/548#548)
- [Where can I get Android 2.2 for HTC Desire](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/542/where-can-i-get-android-2-2-for-htc-desire/543#543)
- [Should I buy a HTC Desire or an Nexus One (in Australia)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/532/should-i-buy-a-htc-desire-or-an-nexus-one-in-australia/534#534)
- https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/452/what-are-the-main-differences-between-android-2-2-and-ios-4/454#454

Comment: @Jarrod Thanks!

Comment: @KyleCronin my pleasure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes dev intervention to accomplish. Incantations. Goat blood. *Dark magik* - that's right, magic with a *k* for *e**k**stra dar**k***.

So Jarrod took care of business. I imagine this will stay a dev tool unless team@ gets a crapload of emails about it. Something I would *never* encourage just for the heck of it.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info.

Comment: magik with ekstra k, KDE?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for all the flags, but [I was told it was the correct procedure](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76/link-migrated-questions-and-answers-to-user-account/156#156). And there are also some comments as well that I was unable to flag. In general, it's pretty safe to assume if you have content that is attributed to "Kyle Cronin" but without an account associated, it's stuff that I contributed to Gadgets and would like associated with my account here. Thanks.

Comment: I think the SE people were more actively monitoring the site right after the Gadgets migration, so flagging worked then.  It would be nice if the regular mods had the power to merge "dead" users with real users, or something.

Comment: @MatthewRead You're right, after a few months they probably thought I forgot or didn't care, or that there were no further issues. And as a moderator on another site, I completely agree that we should have the ability to deal with situations like this ourselves without needing to involve the dev team.

Comment: @MatthewRead: for the time being, you can either post here like you did, or just contact the community team via the usual channels and we'll route it. If there's a significant *volume* of these requests, we can look at other options. These should be fairly *rare* though.